# Timestamp with timezone in PostgreSQL + Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp

I have a column in the database (PostgreSQL).
I want to insert the current time in GMT in this column.
When getting the current time and inserting it into the DB
it's inserted in the server timezone GMT-5 although that time was in GMT+0.
Any ideas how to insert this time in the database in GMT timezone?

Answer (score 4):

## Always UTC in Postgres

Understand that Postgres *always* stores values in a column of type [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), that is, with an [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

So the name is bit of a misnomer, in that no time zone is actually being stored. Instead, any time zone or offset indicator arriving with an input is used by Postgres to adjust to UTC. After adjustment, the UTC value is stored to the table while the zone/offset indicator is discarded. If you care about the original time zone, you must write that yourself to a second column.

What makes things confusing is tooling and middleware such as the [*psql*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#psql) console client app. These often are opinionated, choosing to inject some default time zone adjustment onto retrieved values. So while the Postgres database *always* retrieves a date-time in UTC from any `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column, you may see otherwise on your receiving end. Such a feature, while well-intentioned, is an unfortunate anti-feature to my mind.

Fortunately, I have not seen any [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) that performs such an adjustment. You should always get a UTC value when retrieving an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) from a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column (described below). But test your particular JDBC driver to be sure.

## JDBC and the *java.time* classes

The modern solution for date-time handling in Java is the *java.time* classes.

To capture the current moment, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). This class represents a moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
```

However, despite [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) being the most basic and probably the most commonly used *java.time* class, the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 team made the inexplicable decision to *not* require its support. (Nor is [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) support required, by the way.)

Instead, the JDBC 4.2 spec requires support for [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Fortunately, conversion between `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` is trivial.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Or you can skip the `Instant` class is this case.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Write to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve from the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

This `OffsetDateTime` object will carry an assigned offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds — commonly called just “UTC” as an abbreviation.

Extract an `Instant` if needed.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Or adjust into a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

A caution regarding possible data-loss: The resolution in *java.time* is [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Capturing the current moment is likely limited to microseconds because today’s commonly-used hardware clocks go no finer. Nevertheless, a *java.time* object such as `OffsetDateTime` may carry nanoseconds. Meanwhile, Postgres date-time values have a resolution of [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond). So if using a *java.time* object with any nanos present, writing that value with Postgres will truncate the nanos, resulting in a different value to be retrieved later.

Answer (score 1):

I think paragraph 8.5.1.2 of the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-datetime.html) might be enlightening. It states that by default time is assumed to be without timezone and if one is given it is silently ignored.

In order to make things clear I think it is best to explicitely cast the time :

```
pti=> select timestamp with time zone '20100610T180000-5';
      timestamptz        
------------------------
2010-06-11 01:00:00+02
(1 row)

pti=> select timestamp with time zone '20100610T180000PST';
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2010-06-11 04:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

As is evident the time with time zone  is properly converted from localtime to server time.

Comment: I suppose you mean "paragraph 8.5.2. [Date/Time Output](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT)"?

Comment: No, I meant this : 8.5.1.2. Times

The time-of-day types are time [ (p) ] without time zone and time [ (p) ] with time zone. time alone is equivalent to time without time zone.

Valid input for these types consists of a time of day followed by an optional time zone. (See Table 8-11 and Table 8-12.) If a time zone is specified in the input for time without time zone, it is silently ignored.

Comment: then what should i do, i have a GMT timestamp and i want to insert it in the db with GMT to be in this form:
'2004-10-19 10:23:54+00'
instead of the server timezone '2004-10-19 10:23:54-5'

Comment: times and timestamps are completely different beasts. And your may want to fix that paragraph number if you think that's the relevant info.

Comment: Oops, now I see my mistake, thanks. Yes unfortunately they are very different.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'gmt-5';
```